# Unable to attach a file after clicking upload a copy, tried every possible options

Tags: javascript, automation, cypress

I am trying to upload a file from fixture but I am facing an issue where the element is getting clicked but the file is not getting uploaded. I tried to implement every possible actions but facing the same issue. Is there any other way to upload the file.

```
// cy.get('.relative > span').click({force: true})
// cy.wait(5000)
// cy.get('.relative > span').attachFile('file-sample_100kB.docx',  {force: true})
// cy.wait(5000)

cy.xpath("//span[text()='Upload a file']").click({force: true})
cy.wait(5000)
cy.xpath("//span[text()='Upload a file']").attachFile('file-sample_100kB.docx',  {force: true})
```

[image]
[image: Log data]
Tried attaching file through fixture. Want to attach a file after clicking the Upload a file element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know which version of Cypress you are using, but since the [9.3.0](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/changelog#9-3-0), you can use the command [selectFile](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/selectfile) to simulate a file selection.

Here you will find an interesting blog post that presents this new feature: https://www.cypress.io/blog/2022/01/19/uploading-files-with-selectfile/

Comment: Thank you so much. I am using Cypress 9.7.0 and this method worked like a charm.